# Json data in xcode 9.3

Tags: json, xcode

I just updated to Xcode 9.3 and ran into something a bit strange. The guard statement below fails because the json data can't be cast as shown; though prior to Xcode 9.3 it worked fine (as in Xcode 9.2)

```
guard let dataRates = json?["data"] as? [String : Float] else {
   return
}
```

The issue appears to be with the Float; so, now I need to use a Double as shown below:

```
guard let dataRates = json?["data"] as? [String : Double] else {
   return
}
```

which is fine but why is that required now?

The data is downloaded from the web and serialized as shown below:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
```

... sample data looks like this:

```
▿ 0 : 2 elements
  - key : USDLAK
  - value : 8275.999701999999
▿ 1 : 2 elements
  - key : USDUZS
  - value : 8074.999885

▿ 2 : 2 elements
  - key : USDKWD
  - value : 0.2998
```

Any insight is appreciated.

I should also mention that I'm using Swift 3.2. The Xcode migration tool crashes on me when trying to migrate to Swift 4. This is one reason why I upgraded to Xcode 9.3; hopefully, the migrator works!

Thanks!

Comment: Please add json value in your question

Comment: I've added some more details above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [SE-0170](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md) got included in Swift 3.3 which is what now comes with Xcode 9.3. Xcode 9.2 came with Swift 3.2. So, that explains why this is an issue with Xcode 9.3 and wasn't with 9.2. See [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/305191/) for more details.